# Unable to get BUILD_STATUS global varaible in jenkinsfile

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, pipeline

Im trying to send an email within jenkinsfile, the email subject contain two variable one of them exists on jenkinsfile  APP_NAME and the other one is jenkins Global variable BUILD_STATUS

im getting null instead of the actual value for the build status

```
environment {
    mvnHome = tool name: 'myMvn', type: 'maven'
    mvnCMD = "${mvnHome}/bin/mvn"
    APP_NAME = 'test'
  }



post {
              success {

                  emailext body: '$DEFAULT_CONTENT',
                          to: '$DEFAULT_RECIPIENTS',
                          subject: "${APP_NAME} Health Check: ${env.BUILD_STATUS}",
                          attachmentsPattern: "**/target/${APP_NAME}.jpg"
              }
          }
```

when i changed the subject in the form below

'$APP_NAME Health Check: $BUILD_STATUS'  with single quote i got the actual build status but APP_NAME appears on email $APP_NAME instead of actual name

how i can solve this conflict BUILD_STATUS needs single quote but APP_NAME needs double quote

Comment: I use `currentBuild.result` for this.

Comment: could you elaborate more how i can add it here

 subject: "${APP_NAME} Health Check: ${env.BUILD_STATUS}",

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved By creating new variable includes the BUILD_STATUS global variable

```
  environment {
    DEFAULT_SUBJECT = 'Health Check: $BUILD_STATUS'
  }
```

Then call this variable as shown below

```
 emailext body: '$DEFAULT_CONTENT',
                  to: '$DEFAULT_RECIPIENTS',
                  subject: "${APP_NAME} ${DEFAULT_SUBJECT}",
                  attachmentsPattern: "**/target/${APP_NAME}.jpg"
      }
```